# Format seconds integer to time in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a variable containing time in seconds like `990` which would be 16 minutes 30 seconds. How do I convert this to time `00:16:30` in Groovy?

Along the same lines, how do I convert it the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String timestamp = 
      new GregorianCalendar( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 990, 0 ).time.format( 'HH:mm:ss' )
```

From duration to seconds:

```
long seconds = ( Date.parse( 'HH:mm:ss', '00:16:30' ).time - 
                 Date.parse( 'HH:mm:ss', '00:00:00' ).time ) / 1000
```

Comment: Im not too familiar with `assert` how would you store this calculation back in to a variable?

Comment: Updated answer. Second approach to convert timestamp to seconds can be moved to a method to make it DRYier. I just tried to showcase the gist.

Comment: I'm barely diving into the language, keeping things DRY at this point is way over my head. haha

Comment: Used Groovy `assert` earlier to show expected == actual.

Comment: Not a problem, take your time and stay groovy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here You go:

```
def c = Calendar.instance
c.clear()
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 990)

assert c.format('HH:mm:ss') == '00:16:30'
```

I suppose it might be done a bit smarter in plain groovy ;)

Once again, whole solution:

```
Calendar.instance.with {
    clear()
    set(Calendar.SECOND, 990)

    assert format('HH:mm:ss') == '00:16:30'

    def time = '00:16:30'.split(':')*.toInteger()
    clear()
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, time[1])
    set(Calendar.SECOND, time[2])
    assert (timeInMillis - Date.parse('HH:mm:ss', '00:00:00').time)/1000 == 990
}
```

Comment: This can be optimized a bit with use of `with`. `Calendar.instance.with { clear(); set(Calendar.SECOND, 990); format('HH:mm:ss') }`

Comment: I haven't noticed it! ;] Thanks for the clue! I like the clues You give!

Comment: This is very nitpicky - but also in your `with` you don't need to specify `Calendar.SECOND` or any of the other fields, just `SECOND` or `MINUTE` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this little creature below. Groovy's [sprintf()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#sprintf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29) and a bit of calculations. Unfortunately it doesn't look smart ;)

```
def seconds = 990
assert sprintf '%02d:%02d:%02d', (int) (seconds / 3600), (int) (seconds % 3600 / 60), (int) (seconds % 60) == '00:16:30'
```